# NSString stringWithFormat affects parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am experiencing some weird behaviour and I am wondering if you can explain to me what is happening.

I have the following code

```
@implementation BAClient

NSString* _host = @"localhost:3000";

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
//where the weird stuff happens
        NSString* str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api", _host];
        _connection = [[BAConnectionManager alloc] initWithHost: str];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

after the first line of code runs (after the comment) - _host equals to localhost:3000. when the next line of code runs it equals to localhost:3000/api.

regardless of the code for the BAConnnectionManager constructor code - this is a behaviour I wouldn't expect - as I thought stringWithFormat creates a new string, and even if there is other magical way stringWithFormat works, no pointer to _host should be sent to the constructor.

any way BAConnectionManager Constructor:

```
@implementation BAConnectionManager

NSString* _host;

-(id) initWithHost:(NSString*)host{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _host = host;
        _requestSuccessHandlers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _requestFailureHandlers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

the two are on two different files so the fact that _host is in both of them shouldn't be a problem, or at least it would be a really weird behaviour, because they are defined on two completely different classes.

[image: here is a prove that this is actually happening]

I am under the impression that it really is something about ambiguity here, but I can't figure out why

Comment: And where is `NSString* _host = @"localhost:3000";` defined ? And have you commented out the constructor and retested ?

Comment: How *specifically* are you checking the value of _host to see that it equals "localhost:3000/api"?

Comment: in it's own class - BAClient.

Comment: And it's a global? That you haven't made static?

Comment: I use the xcode debugger

Comment: I added some more context on how it's defined.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I put a breakpoint, and than I look at the watch in the debugger, where you can look at all the local variables.

Comment: Where is _host in BAConnectionManager being declared?

Comment: NSLog the value or use `po` in the console log window -- don't trust the debugger variable display, as it often shows bogus values.  (Likely there's absolutely nothing wrong with the value of `_host`.)

Answer (score 0):

I have got it, since I am a newbie to Objective C I foolishly thought that you create private class members, just between the @implemintation and the @end - any way this fixed it:

```
@implementation BAClient{
    NSString* _host;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
//where the weird stuff happens
        _host =  = @"localhost:3000";
        NSString* str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api", _host];
        _connection = [[BAConnectionManager alloc] initWithHost: str];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

and

```
@implementation BAConnectionManager{
     NSString* _host;
}
-(id) initWithHost:(NSString*)host{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _host = host;
        _requestSuccessHandlers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _requestFailureHandlers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```